# Keyboard with custom touch input under $150

Tags: keyboards

I want to buy a QWERTY keyboard which has features like the [Razer Deathstalker Switchblade UI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008YRITPO). It must have:

- Customizable touch input
- Standard US QWERTY keyboard layout
- Wired USB
- Under $150

In short, I want a cheaper version of the Deathstalker. Is there any keyboard that meets these criteria?

Comment: It's going to be almost impossible to find a keyboard with a touch UI that lives up to Razer's.